# auto complete in shell script

Tags: shell, filenames

My folders are named by date:

- `20140930DoingShellStuff`
- `20140931HopefullyShellIsDone`
- ...

What I want to do is write a shell script to auto `cd` into the folder which corresponds to the current date. I already know how to format the date:

```
date +"%Y%m%d"
output: 20140930
```

But I don't know how to do the autocompletion:

```
cd $(date +"%Y%m%d") **tab for autocopmlete**
```

to get the output of: `cd 20140930DoingShellStuff`

Related link: [Add autocompletion for custom script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128356/add-autocompletion-for-custom-script)

Comment: Have you tried appending an asterisk to the end of the `cd` command? Assuming you are in `bash` and that there won't be two folders with the same date. E.g. `cd $(date +"%Y%m%d")*`

Comment: Thanks, $(date +"%Y%m%d")* works. Although it would be nice to learn how `complete` command works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for folder in $(date +"%Y%m%d")*; do
   if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
     echo "Entering $folder"
     cd "$folder"
     echo "$PWD"
     cd ..
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, $(date +"%Y%m%d")* works. Although it would be nice to learn how `complete` command works

Comment: @SidaZhou you cannot "complete" command inside script in the same sense as you do in interactive shell. `TAB completion` is just a feature added for user convenience but only to use in interactive mode.

Comment: do I misunderstand about [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128356/add-autocompletion-for-custom-script) then? I thought it says we can do autocomplete inside a script(?)

Comment: @SidaZhou I _think_ that user is trying to add `bash` completion to their custom command-line program. Bash is capable of autocompleting things such as flags for a command, which is provided by the `bash-completion` package on Debian.

Comment: @SidaZhou Everything what is written there is about interactive completion. The thing is that shell core doesn't know by itself about external commands and their arguments, so doesn't know what to complete. You need to tell bash about it. And that question was about "how to tell bash that my script expects pkgnames so that they will be completed". But once again - this completion will work only in interactive mode.